# redirecting to login page with locked message if user account is locked

Tags: java, database, spring, ldap

How can i redirect my class on a specific page?  I've implemented counting the invalid login on the page and saving it to the db using application listners. Now i want to redirect to a specific page after N failed login attempts. so before ldap authenticate user, i want to add some entry point in my application so that it checks login counter in database  and if login counter is greater than 5 then it shows login page with locked user account message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(){   
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login");
    if (numberOfLogins>5)
       mv.setViewName(new RedirectView("lockedAccount"));
    //ommited
    retun mv;
}
```